# Raspberry PI5 & QtWebEngine errors :page_allocator_internals_posix.h(225)] Check failed: . : Invalid argument (22)

Tags: raspberry-pi, qt5, qtwebengine, wayland, qwebengineview

I'm passing from rpi3 to RPI5 for my project but i'm having some troubles.
Knowing that Raspberry Pi OS now uses Wayland (instead of X11) with Wayfire (instead of Mutter) by default on Raspberry Pi 5.

I have done the tests in two ways:
1- installed Qt creator 5 on my RPI5
2- did a cross compilation to send a package tar.gz ( my executables and theirs dependencies)
In both tests, i had a black screen ( blank window) when displaying a test.qml.

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtWebEngine 1.9

Window {
    id: window
    width: 500
    height: 300

    WebEngineView {
        id: view
        url: "http://google.com"
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

Setting the QT_DEBUG_PLUIGNS=1 showed me this error:
`**[78882:1:1116/060515.357037:FATAL:page_allocator_internals_posix.h(225)] Check failed: . : Invalid argument (22)**`

So I decided to start with a smaller project since my project is complexe.
The qt example of webengine "Quick Minimal Browser" that showed me the same error.
What's the cause for this ? WebEngine doesn't work with wayland ? Did anyone face that problem ?
Is it a bug that have been fixed in Qt6 ?